# Complexity of recursive code

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I came across this question in a review for my class and I am having a difficult time understanding the professors justification and explanation of the solution. **The question:
The following code computes 2^n for given n. Determine total number of lines executed. Justify your answer.**

```
    Power2(int n)       
    1) if(n=0)
    2)     return 1
    3) else
    4)     k=Power2(n/2)
    5)     k=k*k;
    6)     if(k is even) 
    7)       return k
    8)     else
    9)       return 2*k
```

**The justification**
[image: The professor's explanation]

I don't understand from the "hence" part on. If someone could break these steps down for me a little more and describe how these steps are equivalent, it would be a great help.

Comment: The step `n = 2^k` assumes that the input is always even, and thus only works on the first case for `f(n)`; the *hence...* part is simply the substitution of `2^k` into the recurrence `t(n) = t(n/2) + 1`. From then on it's just simple math to deduce a closed-form solution for `t(n)` in this special case.

Answer (score 0):

```
t(2^k) =                //this is because 2^k is even so
[t(2^(k-1))] + 1        //you apply the first rule for t(n)
```

---

```
t(2^(k-1)) + 1 =        //note that 2^(k-1) is also even
[t(2^(k-2)) + 1] + 1    //so you apply the same t(n) rule
```

---

each 2^(i = 0...k) will be even (except 2^0), so that you can apply the first t(n) rule for all steps, coming to the end of the recursion after **k-1** steps.

then, you note that if you want to evaluate **t(2^k)**, you must do about **k** operations, and **k = lg(2^k)**, so Power2 is a logarithmic-time function,

Answer (score 0):

The line `7)` is wrong it should read `7) if (n is even)`.

Regarding the `Hence` part, they take

> *n = 2<sup>k</sup>*

and show there are *k* iterations. Yet, from above equation we get

> *k = log<sub>2</sub>(n)*

thus having *k* iterations is having *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* iterations.

The algorithm is *O(log(n))*